# Divisors of $p^n-1$ less than $n$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Suppose we have a prime $p$ and a positive integer $n$. Can anything non-trivial be said about the number (say $N$) of divisors of $p^n-1$ that are less than $n$? Of course trivially $N < n$ but can one say anything stronger?

Comment: I afraid we can not say anything non trivial about that... What I could only say is if $n$ is also a prime that the only divisors smaller than $n$ is the divisors of $p-1$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your trivial bound can be best possible.

Let $s$ be the lcm of the positive integers $< n$, and let $p$ be a prime $\equiv 1 \mod s$.  Such primes exist by Dirichlet's theorem.  Then $p^n - 1$ is divisible by $s$, and therefore by all positive integers $< n$.

Comment: I guess what the person asked is, for a fixed $p$, what could we say about $n$... But you're right, if we fix $n$ there are infinite number of $p$ such that $n!|p-1$ and thus $n!|p^n-1$...

Comment: Ahhh yep, this is the type of answer I was looking for. Thanks!